# Reading FIFO doesn't show for the first time

Tags: linux, unix, cat, tail, fifo

In Unix, I've made a FIFO and I tried to read it with `tail`:

```
mkfifo fifo.file
tail -f fifo.file
```

Then I try to write messages into it from another process so I do as below:

```
cat > fifo.file
```

Then I type messages such as:

```
abc
def
```

Before I type `Ctrl-D`, nothing is printed at the first process (`tail -f fifo.file`).
Then I type `Ctrl-D`, the two lines above are printed.

Now If I do `cat > fifo.file` again and I type one line such as `qwe` and type `Enter` at the end of line, this string will be printed immediately at the first process.

I'm wondering why I get two different behaviors with the same command.
Is it possible to make it the second behavior without the first, meaning that when I `cat` the first time, I can see messages printed once I type `Enter`, instead of `Ctrl-D`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just how `tail` works. Basically it outputs the specified file contents only when EOF occurs which `Ctrl-D` effectively sends to the terminal. And the `-f` switch just makes `tail` not exit and continue reading when that happens.

Meaning no matter the switches `tail` still needs EOF to output anything at all.

Just to test this you can use simple `cat` instead of `tail`:

```
term_1$ mkfifo fifo.file
term_1$ cat < fifo.file

...

term_2$ cat > fifo.file
```